# Gatsby: How to pre-process GraphQL results before it reaches page data?

Tags: gatsby

When looking at the static gatsby build I noticed `/page-data/index/page-data.json` contains the entire graphql results in `"result":{"data":{.....`

Is it possible to process these graphql results during the static build, before they reach the final page `data` and that cached json file on the server ?

i.e. run the `transformRawData()` straight after the graphql query is run.

```
const index = ({ data }) => {
   const myTransformedSomething = transformRawData({data.something});
   ... render home page here ...
}

export default index

export const query = graphql`
   {
      ... a few graphql queries here ...
   }
`
```

Comment: I possibly need to look at https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/node-apis/#onCreateNode and modify each node as it is created?

Comment: The `deletePage()` and `createPage()` process outlined here might also work https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/creating-and-modifying-pages/#removing-trailing-slashes 

I'll try both